# PutCassandaRecord using nifi to Amazon Keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi, amazon-keyspaces

I am using nifi 1.10 to push the data into Amazon Keyspaces ,but the problem is Nifi I have only two options for consistency level i.e. SERIAL and LOCAL_SERIAL .

How can I set it to QUORUM/ONE/LOCAL_QUORUM which is supported by Amazon Keyspaces?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use LOCAL_SERIAL as Keyspaces supports LWT.
2. Use the PutCassandraQL processor instead. It has more consistency options. http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-cassandra-nar/1.10.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.cassandra.PutCassandraQL/